# Blurry / pixelated borders in Firefox

Tags: html, css, transform

Basically my issue is that Firefox renders curved borders REALLY blurry / pixelated whenever an element has the "transform:scale" property is applied.

If the properties "border" , "border-radius" and "transform:scale" are applied to an element the resulting curved border is really pixelated but ONLY in Firefox.

CSS:

```css
.element {
   transform: scale(0.25);
   border: 5px solid black; 
   border-radius: 40px;
}
```

** This issue only occurs on the Mobile Version of Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Use `transform: scale3d(0.25)` instead of `transform: scale(0.25)`.

Tested in both Firefox and Chrome.

```css
.element {
  transform: scale3d(0.25);
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
  one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorumet
  Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but is there any alternative way to make this work, as I'm not actually applying the "transform" to a specific element but rather the entire page by using the "initial-scale:0.25" viewport property.

Comment: @BlaineO'neill confused as to what you mean. You say you don't want to apply the transform to an element but have it listed in CSS as `.element`. elaborate further.

Comment: I have asked a more detailed question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71123245/firefox-scaling-issues-causes-pixelated-blurry-borders

Comment: and here is reprex ... https://github.com/blaine-moodley/firefox_border_issues